# Diablo Miner on OSX Lion

Tags: mac, miner-configuration, diablominer

I downloaded DiabloMiner and got it to run by:

1. Using the options: `-v2 -w256 -na`
2. Increase the Java heap size by editing the `DiabloMinder-OSX.sh` file: `-Xmx384m`

And I am getting around 60-70mhash/sec on my MBP (`MacBookPro8,3`, early 2011) /w AMD Radeon HD 6750M, supposedly.

I say supposedly because I get no shares on mining.bitcoin.cz, so I setup the testnet in a box and ran my miner against that and appeared to get no where.

So my question(s):

1. What, if anything, am I doing incorrectly?
2. Is there a better way/miner to be using on OSX(GPU).  Mining information on OSX is very hard to find.

Answer (score 2):

The BitMinter miner also works on Mac OS X. Go to http://bitminter.com and click the "engine start" button. There's no installation, it starts from the browser. It requires Java.

As to what is going wrong with DiabloMiner, I don't know. If it is mining without errors then it should be getting you shares at the pool.

Comment: Tried your miner and I must say I am very impressed... I like the scheduling feature so I can kick on my CPU when I am away.

Answer (score 0):

I never got DiabloWorking correctly; however I did get phoenix2 working with the following config:

```
[cl:0:1]        
    name = AMD Radeon HD 6750M
    disabled = False
    autoconfigure = False
    start_undetected = False
    kernel = opencl 
    worksize = 256 #Appears to not make a diff, using bigger size
    vectors = True #vectors4 is ~2 times slower
    bfi_int = True #Appears to not make a diff, turning on
    goffset = False #MUST be false

    # During use    
    # fastloop = True #Use fast internal loop? (ideal for low aggression)
    # aggression = 3 #Number of nonces to test per kernel execution (lower value = less desktop lag, higher value = higher 

    # Dedicated Mining
    fastloop = False
    aggression = 12
```

Comment: How did you get Phoenix2 to install?  I seem to have issues getting OpenCL installed...

Answer (score 0):

I cannot get the latest (May) version of DiabloMiner to work on OS X Lion. However, I can get the March release to work using the following options:

```
-w 64 -v 2 -na
```

If you cannot find the older version, let me know and I'll share it on dropbox.

There are a few miners I'd like to test, including BitMinter and phoenix2, for comparison purposes, but haven't taken the time to, yet.

Comment: BitMinter works out of the box for me.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the **author** gives the above options for DiabloMiner to work on OS X. I used to get ~70mhash/s until recently but now I get ~60mhash/s on a 2011 iMac with a Radeon HD 6750M. I assume the lower rate is due to OpenCL change(s) in the last Lion update.

Comment: The most recent version of DiabloMiner has fixed the issues I had with the version that came out a couple of weeks ago.